# Python DataFrame Accumulator Based on Flag

Tags: python, pandas

I have a logic-driven flag column and I need to create a column that increments by 1 when the flag is true and decrements by 1 when the flag is false down to a floor of zero.

I've tried a few different methods and I can't get the Accumulator 'shift' to reference the new value created by the process.  I know the method below wouldn't stop at zero anyway, but I was just trying to work through the concept before and this is the most to-the-point example to explain the goal.  Do I need a for loop to iterate line-by-line?

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=np.random.randint(2,size=10), columns=['flag'])
df['accum'] = 0
df['accum'] = np.where(df['flag'] == 1, df['accum'].shift(1) + 1, df['accum'].shift(1) - 1)
df['dOutput'] = [1,0,1,2,1,2,3,2,1,0] #desired output
df
```

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8NClH.png)

Comment: You need to set a seed `np.random.seed(123)` so we can validate against your expected output.

Comment: Good point.  Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, there's no `numpy` or pandas vectorized operation to do this, so, you should iterate line-by-line:

```
def cumsum_with_floor(series):
    acc = 0
    output = []
    accum_list = []
    for val in series:
        val = 1 if val else -1
        acc += val
        accum_list.append(val)
        acc = acc if acc > 0 else 0
        output.append(acc)
    return pd.Series(output, index=series.index), pd.Series(accum_list, index=series.index)

series = pd.Series([1,0,1,1,0,0,0,1])
dOutput, accum = cumsum_with_floor(series)

dOutput
Out:
0    1
1    0
2    1
3    2
4    1
5    0
6    0
7    1
dtype: int64

accum  # shifted by one step forward compared with you example
Out: 
0    1
1   -1
2    1
3    1
4   -1
5   -1
6   -1
7    1
dtype: int64
```

But may be there's somebody who knows suitable combination of `pd.clip` and `pd.cumsum` or other vectorized operations.

Comment: This is perfect.  Thank you!